# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку начиналась анимация и при каждом нажатии передавался на другой блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, frontend

[image: Скриншот]

При нажатии на кнопку первый элемент приподнимается если можно так выразиться. Я хочу, чтобы при каждом нажатии анимация действовала и на другие элементы поочередно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте сss клас анимации и при нажатии кнопки добавляйте его к елементу с помошью javascript.

например:

```
let current = 0;
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('klass-itema');

window.handleClick = function(){ 
  Array.from(elements).forEach(el => 
    el.setAttribute('class', 
      el.getAttribute('class')
        .replace('active','')
    )
  )

 current++;

 elements[current].setAttribute('class', elements[current].getAttribute('class')+' active' )
}
```

и в HTML

```
<button onclick="handleClick"></button>
```

Comment: Покажите здесь, пожалуйста  https://codepen.io/marco12-star/pen/jOWvoQZ

Comment: Больше спасибо. Я уже чуть не помер решая это

Comment: https://codepen.io/petrov_ivan_petrov/pen/OJMoexv

Comment: С вас апвоте..)

Comment: Да хоть сто... Огрооомное спасибо

Comment: в смысле приймите ответ, мне поинты пойдут

Comment: Есть ещё один последний вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы вот здесь при каждом нажатии заполнялся цвет. Перейдите по ссылке, нажмите на кнопку и вы поймёте https://codepen.io/marco12-star/pen/MWKPpMp